# Doing firmware update on a Cisco modem+router DPC2320

Tags: router, updates, firmware

I have DPC2320 Cisco modem+Router. I want to do a firmware upgrade. How could I do that? I am really clueless.

*Note: I have tried to connect router to my laptop using rj45 to rj45 cable, and try to telnet the router using putty, but failed. I get my router from my ISP, so it's ISP equipment. I've already asked this question on Serverfault, it says that I can't do upgrade on ISP equipment, is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a popular ISP provided cable modem. If this modem is provided by your ISP, you cannot upgrade the firmware or access any special areas of the device.

The service provider controls the firmware and customizations. They maintain sole access to any command line tools, or other backdoor configurations.

You, as the customer, can login to the web interface and adjust basic settings of the router which include changing IP addresses, wireless settings, and firewall settings.

**If you have concerns about firmware, or router problems you need to contact your service provider.**

Comment: So, just to make things clear, you said that " . . . maintain sole access to any command line tools . . ", Is it means that I can't get into router CLI?

Comment: The service provider does not want you to have access to a command line. Whether it is possible or not, via hacking, or whatever, I do not know. That is outside the scope of this forum.

Comment: Okay, then. Thanks for your quick response. I appreciate that :) . But I still have questions in my mind, cause I'm really new to this field. I think I'll figure it out my self.